# Conditional logging in python

Tags: python, logging

I want to include logging in a module, but I don't want the module to create a new log object/file, I want it to use the callers log object, whatever that may be, but only if they pass one.  I know I could put all my log calls in a try block, but that's awkward.  What I finally came up with seems to work, but it seems pretty kludgy and I'm sure there's a better way to do it.

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, log=None):
        if log == None:
            class log(object):
                def error(self, msg): pass
                def warning(self, msg): pass
                def info(self, msg): pass
                def debug(self, msg): pass
            self.log = log()
        else:
            self.log = log
        self.log.debug('Starting')
```

What's a better way to do something like this?

Thanks!

Comment: I think it is rather nice. Just put your log class into a singleton and call it NoneLog, or something similar, to reduce the code in each class using it.

Answer (score 2):

Most loggers use the factory pattern to let some centralized resource manage which classes (if any) get loggers which actually log (instead of calling dummy functions). This means that there is a centralized API, centralized control, and there becomes no need to have loggers defined on a class-by-class basis.

It is generally a good idea to view passed parameters as a signal from one thing to another, "You need to use this object to *do your job*." Unless `MyClass` is a logger, it doesn't really make sense to pass it one as a parameter -- it shouldn't need a logger to do its job, if it does that is bad design.

Answer (score 1):

a preferred pattern:

```
import logging
LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class MyClass(object):
    logger = LOGGER

    def do_something(self, somesuch):
        self.logger.debug("Starting %s", somesuch)

myInstance = MyClass()
if need_fancy_logging:
    myInstance.logger = logging.getLogger("FancyLogger")

myInstance.do_something("blabla")
```

EDIT: the standard `logging` module really, actually does everything right, including nothing.

```
Python 2.7 (r27:82500, Sep 16 2010, 18:03:06) 
[GCC 4.5.1 20100907 (Red Hat 4.5.1-3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import logging
>>> log = logging.getLogger('foo')
>>> log.debug('debug')
>>> log.info('info')
>>> log.error('error')
No handlers could be found for logger "foo"
>>> log.error('error')
>>>
```

Note that absolutely *no* output occurs, except a warning is printed *once* to indicate that message was consumed and that this particular logger is blame.

Comment: I think I'm either missing something or not making myself clear.  The class I am writing would be used by others and I have no control over what they do.  I want to log messages if they have set logging up, but I don't want to dump to stdout (as I believe it would) if they have not set up a log file.  Would your method facilitate that?

Answer (score 0):

Use the functions provided by the `logging` module directly, i.e.:

```
logging.debug('Starting')
```

and leave it up to the caller to change the root logger if they want to.

Comment: I don't follow.  If they didn't pass a log object, how will this work?

Comment: The logging module is part of the standard library, and doesn't require passing a custom log object to each imported module.